# Azure and RHEL - "Can't open display :1"... sometimes

Tags: azure, vnc, rhel7, x11

I have an RHEL image on Azure that we launch to perform some specialized tasks.  There is not an option to actually keep the service running.

However, **sometimes** on startup, when I attempt to run even just `xeyes`, I get the following error:

> $ xeyes
>   No protocol specified.
>   Error: Can't open display: :1

Other times, when we start it up using the **exact same methodology** everything works just fine.  I can run everything from `xeyes` to VNC and all is just fine.  I even take special precautions when creating the VM before running the `waagent` command since we launch the image in a *Scale Set* like creating the VNC instance (detailed later) and whatnot under a new user I add strictly for that purpose.

So here's my questions:

- Does anyone know of any oddities that would cause this erratic behavior?
- Is there anything anyone does to ensure that X starts?
- Is there anything I can do to force VNC, etc. to start after X?

**Note**:  I don't need to set up remote X access, just local.

The basic instructions that I followed are [the Red Hat RHEL 7 TigerVNC instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-TigerVNC.html) on the Red Hat site itself.

My workaround, at this point, is to build the VM with Chef and then kick off a process to rebuild everything using those instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment yet, so I am putting this here.

I know this has a down-vote, but I tried this on my Azure account.  I scaled up about 20 instances of the VM and not all of them worked - some did, some didn't.  When I launched it again, I got a different number of up/down instances.

I added a shell script that follows the instructions link you provided to set up VNC in the request for launch.  That seemed to work.

It works, but the only caveat was I had to wait for the network to become available.  All I did special was add a `ping -c 1 -W 1 SOME_REPO_URL` and check the response code to wait for the network to become available (I had some issues with that).

It's a hacky work-around, but it at least functions.

Comment: That is basically what Chef is doing for me.